# Find shortest path in graph that visits 2 nodes from a certain node set

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

> We're given a graph $G=(V,E)$, nodes $s\neq t\in V$ and a subset of nodes $U \subseteq V$ such that $\emptyset\neq U\neq V$ and $s,t \notin U$.
>
> For every path $P$ we'll use $l(P)$ as the length of the path (number of edges) and $P(U)$ will signify the number of $U$ nodes in the path.
>
> I need to find an algorithm that finds a path from $s$ to $t$ and travels through $U$ twice and the path is minimal from other possible paths. That is the algorithm must return a path from $s$ to $t$ such that $P(U)=2$ and if there're other possible paths $P'$ from $s$ to $t$ such that $P'(U)=2$ then $l(P')\ge l(P)$.
>
> It is possible that there're not simple paths, that is a path may go through a node more than once.

A tip that was given in the exercise is that the problem should be solved with reduction.

I don't really see how to reduce the problem. I was thinking that first should run BFS algorithm in order to find a node that belongs to $U$. But once we find a node in $U$ I'm not sure which node from $U$ to choose next (provided $|U| \ge 2$) in order to stay in linear run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new graph, which consists of 3 "copies" of $G$. Each node $(a, n)$ of this new graph represents a situation "I've got to node $a$ of original graph and have visited nodes from $U$ exactly $n$ times". $n$ can be 0, 1 or 2.

Now you need to prepare edges. Edges would be directed and the rules are quite obvious: original edge between nodes $a$ and $b$ corresponds to several edges in a new graph: $(a, m) -> (b, m + x)$ where x is 1 if $b$ belongs to $U$ and 0 otherwise.

And now you only need to find a shortest way from $(s, 0)$ to $(t, 2)$.

Comment: Did you mean $n$ in $(a,m)$ instead of $m$? If not what is $m$?

Comment: @Yos I've edited the answer to make it more clear. I think it's not important which letter ($n$ or $m$) to use in the last sentence, meaning is the same: number of times I've visited nodes from $U$ so far. I'd rather use different letters because the contexts are different: $n$ was used when I described the nodes of the graph, $m$ - when describing edges creation rules. But you can substitute $m$ with $n$.

Comment: Do you think you could describe the algorithm in more detail? For example $n$ is $0,1$ or $2$ but what if $|U| \ge 2$? Do we stop counting nodes from $U$ once we hit $2$? Also when you say 3 copies does that mean that an original node become a "triangle" of 3 connected nodes?

Comment: @Yos So, the nodes of the new graph have form $(a, n)$, where $a$ is a node of original graph, and $n$ is a number 0, 1, 2. "2" here is not $|U|$ or $|G|$. This is a number of times you have visited nodes from $U$ along some path. Suppose you move $a->b$ in original graph, having not visited any nodes from $U$ yet, and $b$ belongs to $U$. This will correspond to transition $(a, 0) -> (b, 1)$ in a new graph. Your purpose is to reach $t$ in original graph having visited nodes from $U$ exactly twice: that would correspond to reaching node $(t, 2)$ in a new graph.

Comment: @Yos You can imagine the new graph having 3 layers. Each layer looks very much like original graph, except that edges are directed now, so instead of one edge $a - b$ there are two edges "back" and "forth". And if the edge leads to a node from $U$ it actually leads one layer higher (if there is a higher layer).

Comment: I drew an example (https://imgur.com/a/nRx59) of a simple graph that has such a path from $s$ to $t$.Is this what you meant? In my example it looks like the path could be found by visiting $s$ from $G_1\to$ $u_1$ from $G_2\to$ $u_2$ from $G_3$ but them we also need to check blue edges in the last layer ($G_3$). However we could've also found the path by visiting $s$ from $G_1\to u_1$ from $G_2\to u_2$ from $G_2\to t$ from $G_3$. What path should be chosen?

Comment: @Yos. Nice picture. Some amendments required. All nodes on first level should have form $(a, 0)$, all nodes on second level: $(a, 1)$, etc. New graph has no "blue" undirected edges, only grey directed edges. Edge $s - t$ should be replaced with two edges $(s, n)->(t, n)$ and $(t, n) -> (s, n)$ on each level (total 6 edges). Edge $s - u_1$ should be replaced with directed edges $(s,0)->(u_1, 1)$, $(u_1, 0) ->(s, 0)$, etc., total 5 edges. And so on.

Comment: @Yos  Now for every path on original graph there is a corresponding path on a new graph, which goes through the same letters, and increases level each time the original path visits a node from $U$. (Well, if original path visits a node from $U$ third time, there would be no corresponding path in a new graph because there are no nodes like $(a, 3)$ in there, but we are not interested in such paths.) And for each path on new graph there is a corresponding path on original graph. Path from $(s, 0)$ to $(t, 2)$ corresponds to path from $s$ to $t$ with 2 visits of $U$ nodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68135/discussion-between-yos-and-lesnik).